# lost dual boot 16.04 & 14.04

Tags: grub2, dual-boot

After working many years orderly suddenly Ubuntu 16.04 disappeared from Boot menu and I only can boot 14.04. Both are on the same HDD.

I tried boot-repair and choosed Ubuntu 16.04. LTS to boot from as first priority, which is on sda5. After this I got a message :

```
dpkg-error found. Pls insert in terminal : 
sudo chroot "/mnt/boot-sav/sda5"  
dpkg --configure -a
```

After I have done this I got :

`dpkg: error: unable to access dpkg status area: No such file or directory`

My problem is very similar as described in https://superuser.com/questions/1561721/boot-repair-disk-unable-to-access-dpkg-status-area-in-debian

I tried also [Super2 Grub Disk and Rescatux](https://www.supergrubdisk.org/super-grub2-disk/) without succsess and the whole thing took me a couple of days of time already.

Comment: The step of mounting `/var` is necessary according to your link. Did you confirm the it is mounted? The next step would be to boot off of a USB image, mount `/dev/sda5` and any other needed partitions, chroot into the installation, and then try the repair. FYI, I would normally suggest asking this on AskUbuntu but the question would be closed immediately as very Ubuntu installations are past EOL .

Comment: I used boot-repair in the same way as in the link and I got the same failure message but I do not understand the solution. I do not know which code to put after grub> or when on Live CD boot-repair.